# issue in opencart product page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

hey guys i have issue to display the category module inside the product page

i went to the layouts and added the module into the layout and tried it on the right side ( position ) but unfortunately it did't show up :(
tried to take a look @ the product/product template but no errors found 
and i tried everything to make it work like creating another layout with the same get link and created the same module in the same position but unfortunately it didn't work :(

so please guys am wondering how can i debug something like this :(

this is the layout screen 
note : screen appears in arabic language dont panic its okay :D
[image]

Comment: Are you using any custom theme or default theme ?

Comment: custom theme and its not even working on the default too :(